# How to drag and drop a control from one TabItem to another TabItem in SWT

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, swt

I am trying to use DND (drag and drop) in SWT. It seems to be working fine for a `TreeView`. I want to drag and drop a control (Label as of now) from one TabItem to another TabItem within a TabFolder.

Here I create a TabFolder and two TabItems and use setControl to define what is inside each TabItem

```
class DNDTab {

    TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder(composite, SWT.NONE);
    tabFolder.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL,GridData.FILL, true, true));

    tabItem = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    tabItem.setText("Favorite");
    tabItem.setControl(new CompositeFav(tabFolder));

    tabItem = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    tabItem.setText("Verified");
    tabItem.setControl(new CompositeVerified(tabFolder));
}
```

Here the verified TabItem is defined

```
class CompositeVerified extends Composite {
    CompositeVerified(Composite parent) {
        super(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, false);
        setLayout(layout);

        String[] testList = {"My TestCase 1", "My TestCase 2",
                "My TestCase 3", "My     TestCase 4", "My TestCase 5"};

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            final Label dragLabel = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
            dragLabel.setText(testList[i]);
            creatingDragSource(dragLabel);

            /*** createDragSource is my defined function where each label within the TabItem 
             * is made as a drag source using "DragSource source = new DragSource(dragLabel, operations);" 
             ***/
        }

    }
}
```

Here the Favourite TabItem is made as a drop target

```
class CompositeFav extends Composite {
    CompositeFav(final Composite parent) {
        super(parent, SWT.NONE);

        DropTarget target = new DropTarget(parent, operations);
        target.setTransfer(types);

        target.addDropListener(new DropTargetListener() {
            /*** The part of the code where dragEnter, dragOver, drop events are added***/
        }
    }
}
```

The drag source is being created fine, and the drag seems to work. But when I drop it into the Fav TabItem, it doesn't get added there.

Answer (score 0):

The tabFolder catch the dropTargetEvent first... 
Ugly hack:

- create dropTarget for tabFolder
- forward the dropTargetEvent to the target composite

Like this:

```
DropTarget target = new DropTarget(tabFolder, DND.DROP_MOVE | DND.DROP_COPY | DND.DROP_DEFAULT);
        target.setTransfer(transfers);
        target.addDropListener(new DropTargetAdapter() {
            public void dragOver(DropTargetEvent event) {}

            public void dragEnter(DropTargetEvent event){}

            public void dragLeave(DropTargetEvent event){}

            public void drop(DropTargetEvent event) {
                DropTarget target = targetComposite.getData(DND.DROP_TARGET_KEY);
                target.getDropListeners()[0].drop(event);
            }
        });
```